cosmicsting security patch for magento 2.4.0
Adobe has released security patches to address the "Cosmicsting" vulnerability. These patches are only available for the following versions:

My question is: if I want to apply this patch on Magento Open Source 2.4.0, where can I find the official patch for that?

Magento versions 2.4.0 through 2.4.3 are now out of support since november 2022. I think the only chance you have is to upgrade your Magento installation.
